# code to activate Eth amount from Ropsten network to Main network

Tags: ropsten, mainnet

I have 2 issues with my Ethereum at Metamask.

1. I received 1 Eth from someone in Africa, sent to Metamask, but he sent to Ropsten network, not to Main network. He asked me to send Dagcoins first and then he will send me a code to activate the 1 Eth to be able to move to Main network. Is this true? that special code will be able to move to Main network?
2. Can I just move balance on my Ropsten network to Main network by myself, without any code or special assistance?

Hope to get a helpful information.

Warm regards from Bali, Indonesia.

Adrian

Answer (score 2):

> I received 1 Eth from someone in Africa, sent to Metamask, but he sent to Ropsten network, not to Main network. He asked me to send Dagcoins first and then he will send me a code to activate the 1 Eth to be able to move to Main network. Is this true? that special code will be able to move to Main network?

No, this is a scam.

He's sent you Ropsten test ETH, which is valueless. (Ropsten is a test network.)

> Can I just move balance on my Ropsten network to Main network by myself, without any code or special assistance?

This isn't possible. There's no way to convert from test ETH (value = $0.00) to main net ETH (current value = $3,400).